# I am able to move the picture for once but how to move it constantly

Tags: javascript, html, css

onclick ='myFunction()' Try it 
`function myFunction() {
var img = document.getElementById("snake").style.transform = "translate(20px)";
    img.transform++;`
}

Comment: Are you looking for `setInterval`? Also, it looks like you have at least some code, can you post a minimal example of what you have now?

Comment: Hello guys,sorry for my ignorance.Im beginner on html and i want to move an image constantly.But im just able to move it for once.I checked w3school.com for answer but i couldn't find.I would be appreciated if you can help.Thank you.

Comment: In my understanding "move constantly" means "move and stay there". That's what your code should achieve.

Comment: I want image to move 20px as an example but continously.But for further level i want it to move according to keypress by user.I think chrisz's solution seems to be useful.Thank you chrisz.And im sorry about my question because there are also animation so i get confused which would be useful for my question.

Comment: Re-format your code with what are you trying to achieve + problems you have + and what have you tried so far.

Comment: I'm basically trying to create a snake game.I have used some codes that i have seen from videos to move the snake.But i couldn't make them work.The code that i took from w3school just provides my snake image 1 move.But as u know from the snake game the snake moves continously on specific direction on keypress of the user.So thats what i want to do.My code is just about this guys.I dont know where can i learn about solutions that question i have in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` function of javascript to achieve the same